# Multiple rows to single row with mulitple columns with Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like the below, I want to do 2 things.  1st. Select the Min(EnterDtm) records, in this case that wold be 2015-08-25 05:29:44:480.  I also want to have a single record row that has height Feet, height inches, and weight kg as new column names and underneath each new column is the ObsText

```
EnterDtm                 ObsCatalogName    VisitID  OBSTEXT
2015-08-25 05:29:44.480 AS height feet NU   219975  5
2015-08-25 05:29:44.480 AS height inches NU 219975  5
2015-08-25 05:29:44.480 AS weight kg CAL    219975  88
2015-08-25 07:05:11.173 AS weight kg CAL    219975  90.6
2015-08-26 06:36:43.537 AS weight kg CAL    219975  90.5
2015-08-26 21:22:21.550 AS height feet NU   219975  5
2015-08-26 21:22:21.550 AS height inches NU 219975  6
2015-08-26 21:22:21.550 AS weight kg CAL    219975  90.5
2015-08-27 05:55:27.373 AS weight kg CAL    219975  87.4
```

I want it to look like this

```
 EnterDtm                  VisitID  Height Feet  Height Inches  Weight
 2015-08-25 05:29:44.480    219975  5             5               88
```

Comment: 3 case statements a max and a group by or pivot if your engine supports it.  What RDBMS is this?

Comment: So if 2015-08-25 07:05:11.173 was the earliest date... you wouldn't have height data right?

Answer (score 0):

First I generate a set of data in a common table expression `With cte` (you could just as easily use an inline view) containing the fields in the format you need using case statements.

This also combines the fields into one record by using amx based on the date and visit and assigns a rank to the visits ordered by the date.

I then select all records from the data set generated in the CTE where the rank is 1 (the lowest enterDTM) for each visitID

UNTESTED:

```
With CTE AS (
Select EnterDTM
,OVisitID
,max(case when OBSCatalogName = 'height feet NU' then OBStext end) as [Height Feet]
,max(case when OBSCatalogName = 'height inches NU' then OBStext end as [Height Inches]
,max(case when OBSCatalogName = 'weight kg CAL' then OBStext end as [Weight]
Rank() over (partition by VisitID, EnterDTM order by enterDTM) RNK
FROM TableName A
GROUP BY EnterDTM, VisitID)
Select  from cte where RNK = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Pivot query

```
select
 EnterDtm,
 VisitID,
 [height feet NU] as [Height Feet],
 [height inches NU] as [Height Inches],
 [weight kg CAL] as [Weight]
from
(
  select 
    t.EnterDtm, 
    t.ObsCatalogName, 
    t.VisitID, 
    t.OBSTEXT 
 from tbl t
   inner join (select min(EnterDtm) MinDtm  from tbl) t2
   on t.EnterDtm=t2.MinDtm
)source
pivot
(
max(OBSTEXT) for ObsCatalogName in ([height feet NU],[height inches NU],[weight kg CAL])
)p
```